# How to show all rows in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to show all rows in a jqGrid table. I know I can use `rowList` to let the user choose how many rows wants to see, but how can I put an option to see all rows? If a put a number like 999999999, it will show all rows because there are less rows, but the user will see that big number as an option and is not too logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use words instead of numbers in rowList as follows:

```
rowList:['All','100','500','1000']
```

Then you have to use your server controller to "convert" that information to a number of rows to show.
I did it like this:

```
Integer intRows = 0;
if (rows.getClass().equals(String.class) && ((String)rows).equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
    intRows = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
} else {
    intRows = Integer.valueOf(rows);
}
```

So your server will show Integer.MAX_VALUE if user selects "All", or a number of rows it other case.
I think you won't have more than Integer.MAX_VALUE rows in your table, it's such a big number!

Comment: I will try it now, but can't I still use numbers except for that "All"?

Comment: Sure, you can mix numbers and words in that rowList. Think about it as  an Object array in Java.
Then your controller will have to detect if the rows params is a word "All" or a number.