# NaN showed in pager

Tags: jqgrid

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240317/how-to-show-all-rows-in-jqgrid) to get an "All" option in pager to show all records in the jqGrid.
But now I have a problem. 
When I load all rows in the jqGrid, the part of the pagers that shows "View 1 - 20 of 544" when I select 20 rows shows "View NaN - NaN of 544" when I select "All" rows.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are asking the server to show `Integer.MAX_VALUE` rows, jqGrid is not able to format that number and shows "NaN".

You can replace NaN in the pager in the `loadComplete` like this:

```
loadComplete: function (data) {
    var pagingInfo = $('#pager_right div.ui-paging-info').text();
    if (pagingInfo.indexOf("NaN") > -1) {
        pagingInfo = pagingInfo.replace('NaN -', '1 -').replace('- NaN', "- " + data.totalElements);
        $('#pager_right div.ui-paging-info').text(pagingInfo);
    }
}
```

jqGrid uses your pager id plus "_right" to identify the part of the pager that shows the number of rows shown in the table.
Inside that element there is another div of class `ui-paging-info`, and its text is the "View x - y of z".